# how to make a http post with param and json payload at same time with openedge requestBuilder

Tags: post, httpclient, openedge, progress-4gl

I need to send a post to an url with parameters and with a json payload.
In Postman, for example, I made this:

`post http://address.com?key=As8941a1891389123812312381923` and in the body put the json in RAW format. On header I just put a Content-type application/json, and it works fine.

In openedge I tryed this:

```
oJson = new JsonObject;
oJson:add('...blablabla',payloadData).
assign cURL = 'http://address.com?key=As8941a1891389123812312381923'.
oHttpClient = ClientBuilder:Build():Client.
Assign oRequest = RequestBuilder:Post(cURL,oJson)
                  :Content-type('application/json')
                  :AcceptJson()
                  :Request.
Assign oResponse = oHttpClient:Execute(oRequest).
```

But, I got a 403 error from the server.
it seems the problem is when I try to send ?key=xxxx parameter with the URL and also a json payload at same time, or, I made a mistake in cUrl formation.

In other kind of posts I made (and that works ok) without a json payload, when has some parameters, usually I have to send the parameters separately, like this:

```
ASSIGN id = trim("db=" + trim(db) + "&lg=" + trim(lg) + "&sh=" + trim(sh) + 
"&sxml=" +      trim(argumentos)) 

htmlRequest = trim(id).
oRequestBody = new String(htmlRequest).

oRequest  = RequestBuilder:Post(trim(cURL),oRequestBody)
            :AcceptHtml()
            :Request.
oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build():Client:Execute(oRequest).
```

how to send both parameter "?key=...." and a json payload at same time with openedge RequestBuilder?

Does anybody can help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your payload a valid json payload? If you set debug-level to 5 then the raw request and responses are exported to your temp directory - compare them with what you are sending via Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your request - with and without the JSON entity - and in both cases the query string is part of the POST.

I'm using OpenEdge 12.2 now and the result is:

```
POST /?key=As8941a1891389123812312381923 HTTP/1.1
Host: address.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 16
Accept: application/json

{"blablabla":42}
```

Here's my test routine:

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

USING OpenEdge.Core.*                    FROM PROPATH .
USING OpenEdge.Net.*                     FROM PROPATH .
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.*                FROM PROPATH .
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.Filter.Writer.*  FROM PROPATH .
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.Filter.Payload.* FROM PROPATH .
USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.*        FROM PROPATH .

DEFINE VARIABLE oJson                    AS JsonObject NO-UNDO .
DEFINE VARIABLE cUrl                     AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oHttpClient              AS IHttpClient NO-UNDO .
DEFINE VARIABLE oRequest                 AS IHttpRequest NO-UNDO .
DEFINE VARIABLE oMessageBody             AS ByteBucket NO-UNDO .
DEFINE VARIABLE oBodyWriter              AS MessageWriter no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE cRequest                 AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

/* ***************************  Main Block  *************************** */

oJson = NEW JsonObject() .
oJson:Add ('blablabla', 42).
ASSIGN cURL = 'http://address.com?key=As8941a1891389123812312381923'.

oHttpClient = ClientBuilder:Build():Client.

ASSIGN oRequest = RequestBuilder:Post(cURL,oJson)
                  :ContentType('application/json')
                  :AcceptJson()
                  :Request

       oMessageBody = NEW ByteBucket()

       oBodyWriter = RequestWriterBuilder:Build(oRequest)
                            :WriteTo(oMessageBody)
                            :Writer.

oBodyWriter:Open().
/* writes the message's contents into the message body */
oBodyWriter:Write(oRequest).
oBodyWriter:Close().

cRequest = GET-STRING(oMessageBody:GetBytes():Value, 1) .

MESSAGE cRequest VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX .
```

Comment: despite my OpenEdge is 11,6 (some of things didn't work) but using part of your code runs ok. Thank you.